# How do I flush STDIN in a PHP console application?

Tags: php, console, stdin, flush, command-line-interface

I have a simple command line utility built with PHP and it works great.  Unfortunately, we now have some lesser than savvy users pounding away at the keyboard while it's processing data.

Is there a way to flush STDIN so it only starts buffering data from when I used fgetc?

I've tried opening my own STDIN pipe and even flushing the buffer by looping through what's in there which kind of works but doesn't handle multiple CRs.

Rewind and fseek don't seem to do anything with STDIN in PHP.

Seems like it would be a common issue but not much out there.

PHP version 5.3.3

(I don't want to use ncurses if I don't have to)

Any fgets or fgetc will exhibit my problem.  For example, if you have a prompt indicating something is "processing" and then start typing away the input is buffered in STDIN so when you actually prompt the user later for something what they type is added to the buffer.  So if they typed "abc" while "processing" and then you prompt for something their input is "abc" plus whatever they typed at the prompt by the time you get to fgets or fgetc.  So if someone keeps hitting ENTER and you're using fgets (or fgetc wiating for a "\n") then you get premature code continuation.

For example:

```
echo "Processing";
sleep(10); // HIT ENTER A FEW TIMES HERE
echo "Input Something: ";
// REALLY NEED TO FLUSH STDIN HERE SOMEHOW
fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. Can you show a simple code example and what it is expected to do?

Comment: PHP has no threading at all, I'm curious as to who thought it was a good idea to write a CLI util in PHP over Python, or Java..  with threaded tech you probably wouldn't have this issue, but i'm not sure EXACTLY what the issue is..

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 Where is this related to threading?

Comment: I tend to say, it can't be achieved. But I'm still unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that PHP "readline" is a good way to handle this and I'm going with it.

Thanks, all!

Comment: Can you explain how it is *working*? At least this example doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/24d9v3HL

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never but you should be able to use stream_select

```
<?php

    while(stream_select($in = [STDIN], $out = [], $oob = [],0)){
        fgetc(STDIN);
    }

?>
```

Basically this would see if there is data available on the given stream and if so read from it (and do nothing with it)

After this you could then read from stdin to get the input you want

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried closing the STDIN stream after each prompt? I think this is how Composer is written. So basically you would go fopen() fgetc() fclose() .... until the next prompt. Works for me but I'm on PHP 5.5

Comment: While you can call `fclose()` on a handle to stdin, you cannot really close it, as the php interpreter still maintains stdin. This answer is plain wrong

Comment: Not elegant in any case.