# How to keep input stream open after piping to PHP process?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, file-descriptor

When a PHP process accepts input on STDIN it seems that no further use of the input stream is possible.

Example: `echo foo | php foo.php`

```
<?php
$file = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
$line = fgets(STDIN);
```

Once the initial stream content has been read, further calls to `fgets(STDIN)` will fail rather than block for new input.

Using the `readline` extension produces the same result.

I can work around this problem by piping to a temporary file and reading from that, but is there a way to effectively keep the input stream open, or prevent it from reaching EOF?

I've tried closing and reopening the STDIN stream, but that doesn't work.

I've also tried preempting EOF by reading only the exact number of input bytes. This does prevent the `eof` flag being set on the stream metadata, but any subsequent read triggers EOF and the same effect is produced.

Comment: There may be something in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php#106905 which talks about working out how much to read from  socket_get_meta_data.

Comment: I've already tried using unread_bytes to stop reading /just before/ EOF. It is possible to leave feof(STDIN) as false, but the next read simply triggers it and you end up in the same situation.

Comment: [This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624075/how-do-i-flush-stdin-in-a-php-console-application) seems to have had some success using `readline`. I haven't been able to check this, apparently forgot to build with `--with-readline` (:.

Comment: I don't have the extension either. Will try adding, although I was hoping for native option

Comment: Update: readline behaves the same as the native method.

Comment: @Tim, I don't get the point of keeping the read end of the pipe open when the write end is closed in your example: `echo foo | php foo.php`. When `echo foo` terminates, then why would you want the command on the other side of the pipe (`php foo.php`) to wait for anything on STDIN (it is closed)?  Consider this: `while true; do echo foo; sleep 1; done | php foo.php`. Here, the write end runs "forever", the write end is "never" closed. Then the read end could do something similar: `while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) echo $line;`.

Comment: The point of further input is to prompt a user for input. I don't really need to justify why I'm asking this. I've already said I can work around it. I'm interested in the behaviour and whether it is possible to use the input stream for these two common purposes in the same script. Your loop example is interesting and probably proves why the answer to my question is "you can't"